# Will Android OS sends any notification when an App is placed to hibernation state?

Tags: android

Android document says that If your app targets Android 12 and the user doesn't interact with your app for a few months, the system auto-resets any granted permissions and places your app in a hibernation state.

My question is if the Android OS will generate any notification to the user so that the user will know the event?

Comment: "Android document says" sounds alike hearsay to me. Why it shouldn't show a notification, which is being delivered by Google Play Services or Huawei Mobile Services? What have you tried so far ??

Comment: here is the link to the document. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#app-hibernation

Comment: I have checked google play service, but have not found any event generated when the app is placed to hibernation state. I will keep searching too.

Comment: @user1443721 Android provides a method to check whether your app is in a hibernation state or not.  The developer has to manually call it and check the state. Let me know if this approach can help i'll share the code here.